# (Zend Framework > Zend_Config) How to avoid using .ini or .xml config?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I don't think that using .ini or .xml file is a good idea with high traffic projects because every page load causes parsing config.ini or .xml file.

Is there any way to replace using .ini/.xml with regular php array as config?
Now php ini looks like that...

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/London"
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = rob
resources.db.params.password = 123456
resources.db.params.dbname = zf-tutorial
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

I want something like this...

```
<?php

$config = array(
    'production' => array(
        ['phpSettings.display_startup_errors'] => 0,
        ['phpSettings.display_errors'] => 0,
    ),
);
```

Is it possible? What should I do and how should I tell application to use my own Config.php?

Thank you and sorry for my English.

**UPD**: I think that passing array to Zend_Application constructor is a right way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use an array to initialize the data for a `Zend_Config` object ; take a look at [this page of the Zend Framework manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.introduction.html) *(quoting what's arround **Example #1**)* :

> Normally it is expected that users
>   would use one of the adapter classes
>   such as `Zend_Config_Ini` or
>   `Zend_Config_Xml`, but if configuration
>   data are available in a PHP array, one
>   may simply pass the data to the
>   `Zend_Config`  constructor in order to
>   utilize a simple object-oriented
>   interface

You should also take a look at **Example #2** on [the same page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.introduction.html) *(quoting what's arround it)* :

> It is often desirable to use a pure
>   PHP-based configuration file. The
>   following code illustrates how easily
>   this can be accomplished

Basically, you first create a PHP file that contains the configuration :

```
// config.php
return array(
  ...
  ...
);
```

And, then, from another file, use than configuration file :

```
$config = new Zend_Config(require 'config.php');
```

But note that doing that, you'll lose the ability to easily modify the configuration, writing it back to the `.ini` file -- which, depending on your situation, might eventually *(or not)* be a problem.

A solution that could be used is to cache the `Zend_Config` data :

- Read it from the `.ini` file
- Store it to some caching mecanism
- And, for the next pages, load it from cache, instead of re-parsing the `.ini` file.

Comment: "And, for the next pages, load it from cache, instead of re-parsing the .ini file." - I will store cached data in something like serialized text and I should unserialize it every time again. It's not a cure. Using php arrays is the only way to speed up loading configs. Yeah, I wouldn't be able to write to config, but it's ok for my situation. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome :-) ;;; If you don't need to write to the configuration file, then, I suppose storing it in a `.php` file will be fine indeed :-) ;;; About caching and de-serialization : it should be a lot faster than parsing a `.ini`/`.xml` file : you'll deserialize an already existing object, instead of re-creating it from scratch *(as you are doing when the configuration is stored in a `.php` file)*

Comment: Or you can use sth. like Memcached ;) That won't require serialization, will it?

Comment: it will, require serialization : an object, in PHP, cannot be stored as-it : it has to be serialized, to be represented as a string -- which can be stored.

Answer (score 1):

A better method would be to cache the result of parsing php.ini. But I don't think this is actually going to be causing you any problems.

Comment: It seems to me that it is impossible to cache parsing php.ini. I can cache serialized data, but I will need to unserialize it everytime again.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to cache it with at least APC or any opcode cache, processing .ini configuration file with Zend_Config is very CPU extensive, especially when using toArray().